# Newline Not Working Inside \pbox After Using \selectfont Command

Tags: fonts, line-breaking, boxes

I have the following command defined for a custom row of a two-column `tabularx` table with column specifiers `rX`:

```
\newcommand{\pbrow}[2]{\pbox[t]{\linewidth}{#1} & \pbox[t]{\linewidth}{#2} \\}
```

The content of the left column will always be formatted using a typewriter font. Now, I need two different typewriter fonts in my document, the first of which, I've set as my default teletype font. For the second one, I've defined the following command:

```
\newcommand{\nkeyw}[1]{\begingroup \fontfamily{qcr}\selectfont #1\endgroup}
```

In the above table, I need the use of this 2nd typewriter font. Since the content of cells are typeset inside a `pbox`, I explicitly need to demarcate the end of line using a `\\`. Therefore, my usage of the `pbrow` command is something like this:

```
\pbrow{\nkeyw{line 1} \\ \nkeyw{line 2} \\ .... \nkeyw{line n}}{Not concerned with 2nd arg}
```

Now this is a bit tiresome, so instead I thought of redefining `pbrow` to format the entire argument with `nkeyw` as follows:

```
\newcommand{\pbrow}[2]{\pbox[t]{\linewidth}{\nkeyw{#1}} & \pbox[t]{\linewidth}{#2} \\}
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting an error because of the `\\`s

Comment: Do you know what the delimiters look like? Or could they be arbitrary?

Comment: It could be anything!

Comment: Could you provide some examples please? Be exhaustive.

Comment: Added the situation!

Comment: How are you switching to the "normal teletype" font, using `\texttt{..}`? How about a switch rather: `\ttfamily`.

Comment: I just use `texttt`. The command for the 2nd teletype font is a scoped one-I don't have to 'switch' to the other one.

Comment: The reason I don't use `\ttfamily` is because I have a normal Serif font for the body of my document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would define a font switch command that can be used inside a cell or `\pbox`. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pbox}

\newcommand*{\nkeywfont}{\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont}
\newcommand{\nkeyw}[1]{\begingroup\nkeywfont#1\endgroup}

\newcommand*{\pbrow}[2]{%
  \pbox[t]{\linewidth}{\nkeywfont #1\unskip\strut} &
  \pbox[t]{\linewidth}{#2} \\%
}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{rX}
  \pbrow{Line 1\\Line 2}{2nd argument}
  \pbrow{foo}{bar}
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remark:**

- I have added `\strut` at the last line of `\pbox` to improve the line spacing to the next table row.

**Alternative**

If explicit line breaks are always used, then a `tabular` can be used instead of `\pbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pbox}

\newcommand*{\nkeywfont}{\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont}
\newcommand{\nkeyw}[1]{\begingroup\nkeywfont#1\endgroup}

\newcommand*{\pbrow}[2]{%
  \nkeywfont
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular} &
  \pbox[t]{\linewidth}{#2} \\%
}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{rX}
  \pbrow{Line 1\\Line 2}{2nd argument}
  \pbrow{foo}{bar}
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Package `array`**

It is also possible to add a command to a cell automatically. It can be overwritten by `\multicolumn{1}{...}{...}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pbox}

\newcommand*{\nkeywfont}{\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont}
\newcommand{\nkeyw}[1]{\begingroup\nkeywfont#1\endgroup}

\newcommand*{\pbrow}[2]{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular} &
  \pbox[t]{\linewidth}{#2} \\%
}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\nkeywfont}rX}
  \pbrow{Line 1\\Line 2}{2nd argument}
  \pbrow{foo}{bar}
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Your first solution is logically the same as mine. You're separating the `\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont` into a separate command, and the newlines are working fine.

Is it because of the `\begingroup` `\endgroup` that errors are being produced for passing newlines to `\nkeyw`?

Comment: @Chatterjee: `\pbox` is more or less a wrapper around `tabular`. Thus its limitations apply, groups are confined to a cell and  groups that crosses cells or rows cannot be used.

Comment: Should I change the title of the question then to reflect my specific situation?

Comment: @Chatterjee: Do what you think is best, I do not have a better suggestion.